# For loop unusual behavior in java

Tags: java, for-loop

While i was writing code for an accounting application , i observed unusual behavior of List in java.  After executing below code,

```
List<String> accountsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i=0; i< (Integer.MAX_VALUE+2) ;i++){
        accountsList.add("Account #"+i);
    }

    System.out.println("# of accounts in list : "+accountsList.size());
```

got output as -  `# of accounts in list : 0` , which was very interesting. Also code ran correctly without throwing any exception. If this is because of value overflow of int, why did not java throw warning/ exception.

Then i modified condition in for loop as,  `for(int i=0; i< Integer.MAX_VALUE ;i++)` and code worked as expected.

Is this behavior has to do anything with Max value of int, as ArrayList can hold values till count of Integer.MAX_VALUE ( accountsList.size()  returns value of type int, and int has max value defined).

Comment: There's a reason it's called `MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: `(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 2) == (Integer.MIN_VALUE + 1)` due to integer overflow... There's nothing unusual about your result.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397475/why-integer-max-value-1-integer-min-value

Comment: Which means `0 < (Integer.MAX_VALUE+2)` returns `false` and you get zero iterations on your `for` loop.  Put a `System.out.print` in your loop to really see how many times the loop is executed.

Comment: Ok, that i understood. But my concern here is why did not java throw any warning/exception meantime.

Comment: I thought Java throws exception when integer overflows, no?

Comment: [Relevant question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15998008/why-do-integer-datatypes-overflow-silently-rather-than-throwing-exception) for Java behavior during integer overflow.

Comment: @user2520968 Please read the JLS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to go above MAX_VALUE, you'll get a large negative number due to overflow.  Technically, there is nothing illegal about this code and the compiler/java will not throw a warning/exception before or at run time.

Answer (score 3):

You try this one

```
System.out.println((Integer.MAX_VALUE+2));
```

The output is -2147483647 that is less than 0 so no values will be added to your list.