# How does arithmetic overflow checking work in c#

Tags: c#

Seems that arithmetic overflow checking is turned off by default in c# due to performance reasons (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/108776/2406234 etc.).

But if I do turn it on, either using the /checked flag or the [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) keyword, how does the runtime in fact perform the check? 
(I'm trying to get a better understanding of what this 'performance hit' is all about.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arithmetic operations, all the way down at the hardware level provide support for indicating if the operation that was performed resulted in overflow.  In many cases this information will simply be ignored (and it'll often be ignored at a very low level), however it's possible to check this result after every single operation and, if overflow occurs, throw a new exception.  All this checking, as well as propagating this information through various layers of abstraction, of course has a cost.

Comment: I'd assume that the actual x86 instructions that run would basically have a conditional branch after every integer instruction, testing the overflow flag (signed) or carry flag (unsigned).  You'd probably set it up so the no-overflow case resulted in non-taken branches.  If you want to be able to identify *where* the overflow happened, every branch would need its own target (which might be a stub that stores a unique value and then jumps to a common handler).  This answer is at least useful to people who don't already know how asm flags / conditional branches work, but is obvious to others. :/

Answer (score 6):

Overflow checking in C# works by using (or not using) overflow checking in CIL.

For example, consider the C# code:

```
public static int AddInts(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Without overflow checking, it would be compiled to something like:

```
.method public hidebysig static int32 AddInts(int32 x, int32 y) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 2
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: add
    IL_0003: ret
}
```

With overflow checking, it would be compiled to something like:

```
.method public hidebysig static int32 AddInts(int32 x, int32 y) cil managed 
{
    .maxstack 2
    IL_0000: ldarg.0
    IL_0001: ldarg.1
    IL_0002: add.ovf
    IL_0003: ret
}
```

As you can see, the CIL form uses different overflow-checking and non-overflow-checking forms of `add`, and the same applies to every operation for which `checked` and `unchecked` affect behaviour in C#. This would be more convenient in a piece of code that mixed a lot of checked and unchecked operations, but the vast majority of the time one mostly combines checked together or unchecked together in methods, so C#'s approach of having a default for the assembly that is overridden in a block is much more convenient for human coders almost all the time.

What happens to this CIL when it is jitted of course depends upon the processor it is jitted to. A likely consequence is either a similar overflow-checked instruction being used (which would cause an interrupt on overflow, which could be used to produce the exception .NET wants here) or a jump-on-overflow instruction like `jo` for x86.

> I'm trying to get a better understanding of what this 'performance hit' is all about.

It is true that `unchecked` is almost always as fast as `checked` and often faster, because ignoring overflow can allow for a more efficient path more often than it prevents one. Simply put, checking for overflow sometimes requires another action, albeit a very fast one at a low-level most of the time, and doing something is almost always slower than doing nothing.* As such in cases where you know overflow can't happen, it does have a slight performance benefit in not checking for that impossible case.

However, this should be considered a secondary feature of `unchecked`.

The primary feature, is that it changes what the arithmetic operations *mean*.

For two 32-bit integers (for example), `unchecked(x + y)` means "add x and y and coerce the result into a 32-bit two's-complement number" while `checked(x + y)` means "add x and y and return the 32-bit two's-complement number that resulted".

As such, when `unchecked(int.MaxValue + int.MaxValue)` returns `-2`, *that is the right answer*, while `checked(int.MaxValue + int.MaxValue)` *doesn't have a correct answer* and hence raises an exception.

They really are different operations, and there are a lot of cases where we *want* the `-2` the first returns.

And as such, our primary concern is "what is the correct answer if we go above the limits of the type?"

1. The answer caused by discarding bits is the correct answer, because we are thinking of these values as sets of bits: Use `unchecked`.
2. We are thinking of these values as integral numbers representing some count or measure, but their being so high means either some sort of mistake, or quantities we aren't prepared to deal with: Use `checked`.
3. We are thinking of these values as integral numbers representing some count or measure, and the math should still be handled correctly for such values: Use `long` or `BigInteger` rather than `int` so you can handle all possibilities correctly. (Perhaps fast-path with just `int` if performance-analysis shows it helps significantly).
4. We are thinking of these values as integral numbers, but we're either confident that they'll never be of such magnitude, or can live with that having weird results because it must be a case of "garbage in-garbage out": Strictly this fits a `checked` use, but `unchecked` will have the same result, so we can use this for the slight performance gain.

Just how often people deal with each depends on what their programming is for. Probably most programs most often deal with the fourth case (how often do your programs deal with more than a few million anything?), the case where we should semantically be using `checked`, but it makes no real difference so we might as well get that `unchecked` performance gain.

The first case is very common in a certain class of cases, particularly relatively low-level code; often programs arithmetic fits the fourth case in most of its "business logic" and the first in a lot of the lower-level stuff libraries are dealing with.

When we need some arithmetic that is close to "real world" math and `int` can't cut it, then we generally still need the "real" result, so we're in some variant of the third case.

Really, the first case of doing some arithmetic and occasionally saying "sorry, I can't deal with this" is very rarely a desired behaviour; `OverflowException` is generally the sort of exception that tells a developer where they have a problem than the sort we catch and then turn into a error message for the user that is helpful to them. As such, most of the time when we have the first case, we *thought* we had the fourth case, but we were wrong.

For this reason it can be useful to:

1. Mark all code that fits the first case (bit-fiddling that should definitely be `unchecked`) as `unchecked` even though that would be redundant with the project defaults.
2. Mark all code that really should throw a `OverflowException` because you'll do something useful with that (rare) as `checked`.
3. Use `unchecked` most of the time for that little performance boost, but use `checked` with debug either all the time, with occasional runs through your unit tests, or if you've got some strange behaviour. (Just where the balance of caution need be here will depend on the application).

*There's also the possibility of branch misprediction, though it's most likely that the non-overflowing case would be the case most often predicted, and also the case most often hit. Generally, branch misprediction isn't as big a risk here as it might be in other cases, including manually checking for overflow.

Comment: What happens if this checked C# code calls native c++ code which cause overflow? Will be the overflow bits on? Even if the checking instruction is not compiled into code. Do I get these overflow exception later? With the next check? What if checked section start new process and wait for the process to exit. Is there something cleaning the overflow result? I suppose these bits are stored in registers and that why the lifetime will be like the lifetime of thread. And that is why it doesn't perform the checking in sub-process, because it is different thread with different registers. Am I right?

Comment: @qub1n I have to say I honestly don't know what happens on the interface between those two.

Comment: @qub1n: Sorry for the long delay; I just saw this now. You are correct to note that calls into unmanaged code which mess with the arithmetic control bits are the most nightmarish global state imaginable for the runtime provider. Back in the 1990s I worked on the MSFT scripting engines, which depend on the arithmetic control bits to be in a particular state, and delphi-authored controls depend on them being in the opposite state, and so a script which calls a delphi control gets into a fight with the control about how the bits are set. That was not fun code to write or debug.